# Flutter: How to set an Instagram story like spotify In Flutter?(I want to share image with app url as story)

Tags: flutter, instagram-story

[image: 1]

I want to share an Image with my app link as an Instagram story when the user clicks on that link it's should redirect to my app. from Spotify app it's possible but I'm not able to do this. from the below code I can show the only image but I need to show an image with URL

```
var value = await SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(
backgroundTopColor: "#EA2A86",
backgroundBottomColor: "#000000",
backgroundResourcePath: bgImage.path,
appId: '1613497035',
imagePath: file.path,
attributionURL:
url);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show an image from a URL? can you explain more about what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to share an Image with my app link as an Instagram story when the user clicks on that link it's should redirect to my app. from Spotify app it's possible but I'm not able to do this. from the below code I can show the only image but I need to show an image with URL @HamidrezaMarzbani